# How to play a video indefinitely on loop on Amazon Fire TV Stick?

Tags: video, power-on, standby, kodi, amazon-fire-tv-stick

I have an Amazon Fire TV Stick and a video file. I want to play on loop for a several hours. I have attached the USB to the Firestick using an OTG dongle. I have the Kodi app to play the video on a loop using a playlist set to repeat all.

But I want to make sure, while it's playing, it won't turn off on its own due to some timeout or sleep setting even if it plays for like 6 hours straight.

Does anyone know if it would happen and what settings to change to prevent this?